# Syntax to validate e-mail address using a regex expression

Tags: commcare

An e-mail address is collected from a participant. 
ex. john.smith@gmail.com or smith@gmail.com

How do you validate an e-mail address using the Validation Condition to ensure:

1. That an `@` and `.` symbol are in the answer
2. There is `.` after the `@` in the answer

Is there a regex expression that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case you're describing, `@` followed by `.` you can use the CommCare regex function: `regex(., '.+@.+\..+')`. See docs on the [regex function](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Functions#CommCareFunctions-regex).

Email validation can get much more complex, check out this page for a more comprehensive regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I used this syntax in the validation and it worked great!             regex(., ".+@.+..+")

Comment: I think you might need to escape the period: .+@.+\..+

Answer (score 1):

Following is the regex which validates the email.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

If you need regex in different language visit this [site](http://emailregex.com/). This site gives you regex in 15 different programming languages